# Output problem when I called 2d array functions from python 3

Tags: python, c

I am a newbie at coding. My sysyem is win10 64 bit.  I'm using CodeBlocks to write C code. Also I'm using Python 3.10.  This is my C code. This function adds the value 0.99 to all elements of a matrix. I want to call this function from python 3. My C file is;

cab2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

c_bes(const int ** s, int R) {
        float** nrm=(float**)malloc(R*sizeof(int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++){
            nrm[i]=(float*)malloc(sizeof(int)*R);
            }
for( int i=0; i<R; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                 nrm[i][j]= 0.9;
            }
        }
    return nrm;
}
```

it works and adding the 0.9 value an n*m zero matrix successfully in C . As mentioned above in order to use this function with python,I compiled this code with this command and I written python code as below.

```
gcc -o c_bes.so --shared -fPIC cab2.c
```

my python code;

Test.py

```
from ctypes import c_void_p, c_double, c_int, cdll, c_float
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np

row=2
col=3

orn = np.matrix([[0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0]])
print (orn)

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/Cfunc_in_pyt_2/c_bes.so")
c_bes = lib.c_bes
c_bes.restype = ndpointer(dtype=c_float, shape=(row,col))
res = c_bes(  c_void_p(orn.ctypes.data),  c_int(row)  )
print(res)
```

my output is;

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]

[[-2.8212709e-34  8.6600245e-43 -2.8212783e-34]
 [ 8.6600245e-43  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]]
```

As shown above this give me wrong output! All matrix element must be 0.9 ! What is my wrong? Despite all my efforts, I can't succeed! Please help me.

Comment: Why are you using `int` to calculate size of arrays of `float`?

Comment: When I use float it gives me same wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirements:
With a C-function, 0.99 is to be added to all elements of a matrix. The matrix is to come from Python.

There are a couple of problems:

- the argument `s` in the C function seems to be the intended Python matrix, but the parameter is not used at all in the C function.
- the type for `s` is wrong, assuming a contiguous array it should just be `float *`
- `c_bes` has no declared return type, you could use `void` since the matrix elements can be manipulated in-place
- if you would prefer dynamically allocated memory on the C side after all, you should use the correct sizes, so if you want to work with a float array, you should not use `sizeof(int)` but `sizeof(float)`.
- if dynamic memory is used, you should also free it after use
- maybe use better naming to make the code more readable, e.g. something like `matrix`, `cols`, `rows` etc
- with the compiler options `-Wall -Wextra` you get helpful warnings about possible problems in the code, use these
- `= 0.9` assigns a fixed value, but actually you want to add something to the matrix element, so use the addition assignment `+= 0.99f`. The `f` at the end indicates that you want to work with a float constant and not a double constant
- in Python, the types of function arguments can be described using `argtypes`
- with `dtype` the desired type of the matrix elements can be specified

If you apply the points just listed to your example code, it might look something like this:

**cab2.h**:

```
#ifndef C_BES_LIBRARY_H
#define C_BES_LIBRARY_H

void c_bes(float *input, int rows, int cols);

#endif //C_BES_LIBRARY_H
```

**cab2.c**:

```
#include "cab2.h"

void c_bes(float *matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            matrix[r * cols + c] += 0.99f;
        }
    }
}
```

**Python**

```
from ctypes import c_int, cdll, c_float
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np

rows = 2
cols = 3

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/Cfunc_in_pyt_2/c_bes.so")
c_bes = lib.c_bes
c_bes.argtypes = [ndpointer(c_float, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS", shape=(rows, cols)), c_int, c_int]

orn = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float32)
c_bes(orn, rows, cols)
print(orn)
```

**Test**

The above code then outputs the following on the debug console:

```
[[1.99 2.99 3.99]
 [4.99 5.99 6.99]]
```

Note that I have changed the input matrix so that it can be seen that the correct operations are performed on the values of the input matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable information and solution.